# Active Directory Requirements

Tags: windows

What are some factors or requirements when designing an Active Directory Infrastructure. ? How do you gather the requirements for the design?

How do you choose the appropriate Active Directory replication topology for your company? What kinds of problems do you want to prevent?

Comment: This is a huge topic. Your question will likely get closed because it is so broad. Start with Microsoft's [IPD Guide for Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc268216.aspx). Additionally, please familiarize yourself with the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) if you haven't already.

Comment: Don't. Hire someone who *really* knows what they're doing if you want it right. If you want to know why they made certain decisions they should be glad to provide training. The questions you're asking could easily fill several books (actually the [MCSE: Server Infrastructure](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcse-server-infrastructure-certification.aspx#fbid=rjf3TdW5ntd) certification covers this in 5 separate books, and even that's pairing it down).

Answer (score 2):

I'll start.

Some factors would include:

- Number of users
- Number of servers
- Number of sites
- Distance between sites
- Odds of a user moving between sites during one work day
- You want to prevent timeouts when logging in
- You want to ensure that there's always domain controllers and DNS servers active at each site at each time
- You want to ensure that there's always a way for users to login